# How to check if a data sequence is really random?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, randomness

I wonder how can I test if a data sequence is really random?

Of course I can randomly cut it into equal pieces, and check if the correlation coefficient between different pieces on average is zero.

But is that sufficient?  Or if that is the best way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: In the context of your situation, what is the definition of random?

Comment: Additional answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+diehard.